# Do I need to cleanup files created by tempnam() myself?

Tags: php, temporary-files

I created a bunch of `tempnam()` files for use during my request. Do I need to specifically `unlink()` them when they're not needed anymore, or will PHP / the system take care of it themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files created by [`tempnam()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam) will not be deleted by PHP.

You'll have to [`unlink()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) them manually.

---

If you need a temporary file thats automatically deleted by PHP, consider using [`tmpfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php):

> Creates a temporary file
>
> **The file is automatically removed when closed** (for example, by calling `fclose()`, or when there are no remaining references to the file handle returned by `tmpfile()`), **or when the script ends**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unlink (delete) temp files when you're done with them. Some, but not all, OSs clean up their temp directories once in a while. But `tempname()` uses directories other than the OS temp directories.